# How to manually remove a bad email message in Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

I am using Evolution in Ubutu 12.04 LTS. I seem to have gotten a bad email message- when I opened it and Ctrl-I to see the images, Evolution hung up as it was "formatting message" and then hung up completely. Now whenever I click on that message in my inbox (I desperately want to delete it), same thing- lower bar say "formatting message", and all of Evolution grays out and hangs. Since clicking on this message to delete it immediately crashes Evolution, is there any other way to manually delete this message from by inbox? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Update- never mind! After over one hour of trying different approaches, suddenly and through no result of my own efforts, this email message did not crash Evolution when clicked, so I could just delete it the usual way. If anyone has suggestions, I would be very curious as to why this behavior and why it resolved on its own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears, you have it answered anyway, but I will add this:
 Mail in evolution is stored with folders and files in the home directory - these are in `.local/share/evolution/mail/local/cur`.

So if you had opened Nautilus (File Manager), pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, pasted in this and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
~/.local/share/evolution/
```

It would of taken you to that directory. Some of these files have names that begin with `.`, so you would also of needed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view them.

Then it is simply a matter of locating the email - the names are in this format:

```
1389219028.4732_4390.COMPUTER-HOSTNAME:2,
```

and are in date order, so if it had been a recent email it would of been easy to find. You can then open the suspect files in `gedit` *(a text editor, so should have no effect on your system)*, and check the top lines against the entry in Evolution - e.g:

```
Return-Path: <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
```

after having found it to be the right one, right-lick and <kbd>Delete</kbd> it.

***Note Below:** Pressing Delete **in Evolution** won't delete the files unless it is enabled to do so - you can still view it by going to the <kbd>View</kbd> menu , and then pressing <kbd>Show Deleted Messages</kbd>  - to get rid of it properly, go to the <kbd>File</kbd> menu , and then press <kbd>Empty Trash</kbd>. This will also remove any other messages you have deleted (should do anyway).*